# Django Media files and Retrofit

Tags: android, python, django, retrofit

We work on a project with `Android frontend` and `django-rest-framework backend`.

The Media files were served through `Django Media files` and we can cache media files and see them in the app when it was offline.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),    
    url(r'auth/login/', 'rest_framework_jwt.views.obtain_jwt_token',name='jwt_login'),        # post username & password to get token    
...

) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The problem was that we need to apply authorization on media files so I've removed `media paths from urls` and add a view to do the job

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def media_image_handler(request,url):
    # extra code before serving media
    ...
    ...
    # read and return media file to response
```

And the url.py changed to this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<url>.*)/$',media_image_handler, name='media'), 
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),    
    url(r'auth/login/', 'rest_framework_jwt.views.obtain_jwt_token',name='jwt_login'), 
)
```

Now we got 2 problems:

1. Due to extra code response time become higher
2. Cache files cannot be loaded offline

Now the question:

> Is there any suitable method that can be used instead?
>   For example instead of full authentication use a random generated file names that cannot be guessed easily or whatever?

We will appreciate for any helpful opinion

> P.S. We are using Retrofit and Picasso on Android

Answer (score 1):

For first: static files should be served by servers like nginx or lighttpd. About your question. I think you are talking about controlled downloads. This feature calls X-Sendfile and implemented in nginx and other servers. You can read about it in Nginx documentation.
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/